# Invalid or corrupt jar file

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, intellij-idea, jar

I have an Intellij Maven project. The program runs both in the IDE and jar file on my local machine. But when I run jar file on another machine I get "Invalid or corrupt jar file". The java version on my two machines is 1.8.303 and the project is built with 1.8.302.

Since this error is so generic I have no idea what to go on. Any idea on this?

Comment: Check that the file didn't get corrupted in the process of transferring it.  For example, use a checksum tool to  generate (say) SHA256 checksums of the JAR file copies on both machines and then compare them.

Comment: I use WinSCP for transferring it. Executing the command to generate checksums I get two different values, however it seems strange for me because I had always used this program for my releases.

Comment: confirm that WinSCP is transferring in binary mode (and be sure it is transferring to the correct destination)